# I have 12000 euro as cash when entering Europe. Any problems?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, money, eu, ams

Does 12000 euro as cash make any problem for entering Europe? I want to leave Turkey to go to Amsterdam as a transit for 1 and a half hours and then to Poland. I have a bank statement.

Comment: You must declare all sums €10.000 and above when entering the European Union (Amsterdam). The customs officials will give you a statement stating that it has been declared that will also be valid in Poland.

Comment: Some countries require travelers to declare holding large amounts of cash when they _leave_ the country. If Turkey has that requirement, you'd also have to declare it before leaving.

Comment: Thank you. since I will be transit from amsterdam to where should I declare? Poland or netherland?

Comment: @Turkan You must do it when you enter the European Union, which in your case is Amsterdam. Note: this is a requirement, so if there no customs control (as someone claimed here recently) after the passport control, you must report to a customs office inside the airport.

Comment: @  Mark Johnson so the transfer time is 1 hour 15 minutes and we just go through transit. Are you sure we need to report it in netherland not poland? we don't take the buggage in netherland and I don't know it is wise to do that or later on in poland? how long does it take to do the process?

Comment: Yes, you must do this when you **enter** the European Union (not at your destination point in the European Union). See [Filing a declaration of liquid assets](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/10_000_or_more/declaration_liquid_assets/filing_a_declaration). You can download the needed form from that page now, fill it out and report to the customs (red channel) and give them the prepaired form.

Comment: @ Mark Johnson sir the transit also has this red channel?

Comment: The airport has 2 areas. 1) Area where flights from/to non-Schengen countries take place. This is also called a **transit** area. (This is where you will be landing, coming from Turkey) 2) Area where flights to/from Schengen countries take place. (This is where your flight to Poland will take off). When leaving the transit area, you are officially entering the European Union and its Customs Area. You must therefore go through the **Border Control** (where your passport will be checked) and then through **Customs Control**. Customs Control has 2 channels (green and red).

Comment: You must go through the red channel, because you have something to declare.

Comment: @Relaxed For France only the declaration issued in Amsterdam needs to be shown. [Examples of when a declaration must and must not be filed for liquid assets](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/10_000_or_more/examples/). In Poland it is not required when crossing and internal Schengen border. [border.gov.pl](https://granica.gov.pl/faq.php)

Comment: Note that jurisprudence says you must make that declaration even if you are only in transit between two non-EU countries, so it's clear that even in the non-EU-to-EU transit you must declare in Amsterdam. In many cases, border control for transit passengers does not include visible customs facilities (don't know if that's the case in Amsterdam). Ask the passport control officer once you're done with them, they will let you know where you can make that declaration.

Comment: Note also that Turkey has been added to the french red list yesterday, so it's likely it has been or will shortly be added to the red lists of other EU countries. This could severely affect your travel plans.

Comment: @jcaron what do you mean severely affect? Nothing will be happened

Comment: @Turkan When countries put in place additional restrictions due to the Covid situation, their reaction can vary from nothing to full ban (see Australia), no flights, mandatory hotel quarantine (see UK, Australia, New Zealand), etc.

Comment: I reach. Nobody checked anything. Passport control was on netherland. Luggage in final destination not checked. Two officers were in final destination maybe random check.

Answer (score 7):

You need to file a declaration in Amsterdam.
Relevant example from [belastingdienst.nl](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/10_000_or_more/examples/)

> Example: flight from Tokyo to Paris via Amsterdam

> You are flying from Tokyo (Japan) to Paris (France) via Amsterdam (the Netherlands).
> You arrive in the European Union in the Netherlands.
>
> - **If you leave the flight in Amsterdam (the Netherlands) (transfer), you will have to file the declaration in Amsterdam (the Netherlands). You can use a copy of your declaration to demonstrate in Paris (France) that you have filed a declaration in Amsterdam (the Netherlands) for the liquid assets.**
> - If you do not leave the flight in Amsterdam (the Netherlands) (no transfer), you will have to file the declaration in Paris (France).

The question that remain is how to do it at Schiphol airport. One option is to leave airside to get to customs and then enter through security again. You could look and ask for other options though.

Answer (score -1):

You **must** declare that you carry more than €10.000 once you pass **Customs**. This is likely to happen in Poland.

Netherlands and Poland are in the Schengen Area, so you enter the EU when you first land in Amsterdam.

You have two options to reach Poland then: either by car/train/bus, leaving the airport, or by transiting into the domestic flights area. I understand the second.

Unlike Turkey, almost all Schengen airports do not have separate terminals. In Turkey, for example, you will have to go x-ray controls once again to board a domestic flight coming from outside. In Schengen, you first go **Immigration**, where you are only asked about your passport, and then you will have the option to either go to **Baggage claim** (through a no-way-back door) and exit, or remain in the Schengen departure area.

Once you land in Poland, you will finally go to the exit and **there** you will find Customs. You **must** go to the red lane yourself, or face the risk someone stopping you and confiscating the money.

**If** you need to collect baggage in AMS, e.g. because you are not allowed check-through, then you **must** go through Customs in AMS, but then you will have to make sure that your check-in bags are labeled again with a **green** label grant free access to the Blue Lane of Poland's Customs office.

---

**Sources**:

- [Dutch Customs:Filing a declaration of liquid assets](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/10_000_or_more/declaration_liquid_assets/filing_a_declaration)

  - [download the declaration form, PDF, English](https://download.belastingdienst.nl/douane/docs/cash_declaration_form_iud0952z4foleng.pdf)

> **Please note!**
>
> - It does not matter how you enter or leave the EU (examples: **airplane**, car, motorcycle, ship, bicycle, on foot).
> - It makes no difference how you carry the liquid assets, e.g. as hand baggage, **hold baggage** or in the car boot.
> - You must also file a declaration if you are not the owner of the liquid assets.
> - **You must file a declaration each time that you enter or leave the EU**.
> - **You file a declaration in the country where you enter or leave the EU**.
> - You do not need to file a declaration if you do not leave the flight or ship on which you enter the EU.
>
> **On arrival in the Netherlands from a non-EU country**
> File your declaration by reporting to Customs in the so-called 'red channel' (goods to declare). Inform Customs that you wish to declare liquid assets.

Comment: We have been through this a while ago, on a simular question and it seems that you have to declare when you enter the EU (into the first Schengen country in this case) and there is likely a customs official with the passport control point between the outside Schengen and the inside Schengen part of Schiphol. (But I have never used that part as I always exit at that airport.)

Comment: @Willeke I think you only declare what you have with you (so not checked in luggage) when you stay airside on transfer. So if you carry 9500 euros with you and put the remainder in luggage, I think you won't have to declare at the transit airport (because you haven't reached 10K yet). Then in Poland, you do need to declare because the total of undeclared cash adds up beyond 10K. [Source (see very end)](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/luggage/from_a_non_eu_country/travelling_from_outside_eu)

Comment: This answer is misleading. It is correct that your **hold luggage** will be processed at the destination point. But as a **person** (including hand luggage) you will processed at the point of entry. Quote from the Dutch customs page: *It makes **no difference** how you carry the liquid assets, e.g. as hand baggage, **hold baggage** or in the car boot.* In case of a violation: *you risk facing a minimum fine of € 1,000 and a maximum fine of € 20,250 or a term of imprisonment.*

Comment: @JJJ That is not correct. Liquid assets contained in the **hold baggage** must also be declared at the point of entry. Poland may then will ask you to present the declaration of liquid assets form (which you won't have based on your assumption).

Comment: @MarkJohnson but isn't the point of entry of the hold luggage at the final destination? How can you declare something to which you don't even have access (at the port of transit)? Even if you are correct, the luggage won't get to Dutch customs so they can't fine you. And the Polish authorities probably won't make a fuss as you declare it to them. Under my assumption you would follow the same procedure as when you declare goods (in hold luggage) with the same itinerary.

Comment: `KLN`, `NAP`, `WAW`, `VNO`, `BGY`, `LGW` (it was EU...). In my experience, you pass customs only after you collect your bag and not during transit. This is why I made my first revision of the answer. Now, I admit I've never been in `AMS` where things may be different.

Comment: @JJJ I have added the statements from the Dutch Customs where they **explicitly** state that liquid assets in **hold baggage** must be declared in the country where you enter or leave the EU.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yea, I agree that the source supports your position. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if the source has considered the transit option with the liquid assets in hold luggage. For example, how will they check that your filing is correct? I assume they'd want to verify your form with the physical assets you are declaring. I wouldn't be surprised if they would tell you to file in Poland if you cannot produce the assets in the transit area.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ It really doesn't matter. Where there is no Customs control, you are **required** to go to the nearest Customs office and make the declaration.

Comment: @JJJ You are not in transit. You are entering the EU and are flying to another destination within the Schengen Area.

Comment: @Willeke Schengen and EU are different areas. A customs officer at the passport control won't help passengers from for example Norway (in Schengen but not in EU)

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, but the hold luggage doesn't pass customs until the final destination. If we were talking about regular goods (in hold luggage) then you would simply declare them at the final destination. That's why the baggage tags in Schengen get the green bars whereas tags from outside Schengen don't. Those tags indicate to customs officers whether luggage originated from within the Schengen area. Your source appears to say that liquid assets are different, but it could also be that it hasn't considered the transit situation.

Comment: @JJJ When I flew in from the US, through Schiphol, to Berlin there was no customs in Berlin. I asked myself how they could reliably determine which passengers from the internal flight should be checked. So there are many questions as to whether this is efficient or not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yea that's why they have [those green bars on the baggage tags](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/business/customs-controls/travelling-air_en#etiquette_verte). As for reliably checking, I have never been checked after transiting in Europe (including Switzerland), I have been checked (in AMS and BRU) multiple times when flying in directly from Asia. All anecdotally of course, but I think you're more likely to be checked when you arrive from outside Europe (and some flights may be checked more).

Comment: @JJJ If they do check in Poland, then they will check if the total sum has been declared (assuming that you haven't passed €9000 to someone else on the way). The only way to avoid this is to require the hold luggage to presented on entry (as done in the US).

Comment: @Anders, I know that Schengen and EU are different things, but in this case entering the one you enter the other and as the passport check is for Schengen (and not the EU) that was the name I used.